# Convert XML file to QAbstractItemModel

Tags: xml, qt, qcompleter

I would like to build an auto completer for a QtWidget (QPlainTextEdit). The key words I want to use are stored in an XML file. Is there an easy way to get the XML file into the QCompleter? The QCompleter can be called with a QAbstractItemModel or a QStringList. So I hoped there is a function that will turn my XML file into one of these two things. Is this possible or do I have to read my XML file line by line and fill a model or a list?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no automatic conversion from XML to a list, mostly because the XML can have an arbitrary structure. There is [QXmlStreamReader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html) class that you can use to parse the XML and populate the model.

Assuming the XML looks something like

```xml
<keywords>
  <keyword>Foo</keyword>
  <keyword>Bar</keyword>
</keywords>
```

Then you only need a couple of lines to parse it:

```c++
QXmlStreamReader reader(xmlFileName);
QStringList keywords;
while (!reader.atEnd()) {
    // parse next token
    reader.readNext();
    // is this an opening "keyword" tag?
    if (reader.isStartElement() && reader.name() == QLatin1String("keyword")) {
        // add its value to the list
        keywords.append(reader.text().toString());
    }
}

auto completer = new QCompleter(keywords, lineEdit);
...
```

You might want to use the model ctor (e.g. with [QStringListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html)) if you want to populate the completer with data from a different XML file for example based on some configuration, since you can then easily `clear()` and re-populate the model again. You can also share the same model between multiple `QCompleter` instances.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I will try it like this.